# Run an async query and return result once completed

Tags: javascript, express

I know this sounds like it should be a simple google to fix, but i've been spinning my tires for a while now.

I'm using the MSSQL middleware to connect my express app to an MSSQL db.

It runs a stored procedure that simply returns "true" or "false", which it does successfully. My issue is when it returns to "var login", and by the time i've run the code following it, the actual query hasn't returned a value yet. Console output usually looks like:

**console**

```
login is of type: undefined //from console.log executed after db.userLogin is called
returned is: true
```

**routes**

```
userdetails = {};
userdetails.username = "username";
userdetails.email = "email@email.test";
userDetails = JSON.stringify(userDetails);

var login = db.userLogin(activeConnection, userDetails);
console.log("login is of type: " + typeof (login));
```

**db.userLogin**

```
module.exports.userLogin = function (activeConnection, loginDetails) {

loginDetails = JSON.parse(loginDetails);
var username = loginDetails.username;
var password = loginDetails.password;
var email = loginDetails.email;
var returned = "";

var request = new sql.Request(activeConnection);
request.input('username', sql.NVarChar(50), username);
request.input('password', sql.NVarChar(50), password);
request.execute('loginUser').then(function (recordsets) {
    console.log(recordsets[0].length);
    returned = recordsets[0][0].UserExists;
    console.log("returned is: " + returned);
    return returned;
});
```

I'm *trying* to have **var login** contain the "true" or "false" being returned by **userLogin** method.

**userLogin** is just a normal function, it is not a promise (my understanding of Promises is very shaky, so i'm not confident about whether or not it is actually *returning* a promise).

From my reading of docs and experimenting, **request.execute(...)** returns a promise, which is why I am using a ".then" to run code afterwards. However, inside ".then" function, it seems to be returning **returned**, which has not been assigned the "true" or "false" yet. **var login** is also being shown as *undefined* when its type is printed out

I know it has something to do with promises, but every combination of return, .catch, .then I can think of hasn't given me any real results.

**Edit:** added the actual full code block I was using, as well as clarification on what I thought was returning a promise, and what was just a normal function call.

Comment: Your mistake is thinking you can return a value. You can't return a value. You can only pass in function. Either by returning the promise returned by `request.execute()` (which you are not returning BTW) or by passing it directly into `db.userLogin()`. Get used to passing in functions instead of returning values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `db.userLogin()` return promise, you can do this

```
db.userLogin(activeConnection, userDetails)
  .then(function(login) {
    console.log(login)
  }).catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

**db.userLogin**

```
// ... code
return request.execute('loginUser').then(function (recordsets) {
    console.log(recordsets[0].length);
    var returned = recordsets[0][0].UserExists;
    console.log("returned is: " + returned);
    return returned;
});
```

Comment: DO NOT do the Promise anti-pattern. It is stupid and inefficient. LOOK: `request.execute('loginUser').then(...`. So DO NOT do `return new Promise(function(){request.execute().then()...`. Just do `return request.execute().then()`. It's already returning a promise. Do not create unnecessary promises.

Comment: My apologies, tried pulling out my code that I thought was relevant, but didn't explain the rest of it properly. userLogin was not a Promise itself, it was request.execute that returned a promise (it's from the MSSQL module). I implemented what slebetman suggested, and now "login" is of type "Promise". I had it here before, but I had expected the "Promise" to already be set to a value, as I need to use it in some code immediately following.

Comment: Spencel in above comment, me and @slebetman provide a process to turn userLogin return a promise.

Comment: @TiepPhan:  `.then()` returns a promise. That's how promises work

Comment: Thank you both for the answer and details/clarification!

Answer (score 0):

You need to run `console.log("login is of type: " + typeof (login));` inside a callback that is executed after userLogin operation is complete. So probably you need something like this:

```
var login = db.userLogin(activeConnection, userDetails).then(yourCallback);

function yourCallback(param) {
 console.log("login is of type: " + typeof (login));
}
```